# Cannot compile PDF

Tags: compiling, document-configuration

I was using Texmaker on Linux for a couple of internships, now I moved to Mac OS X, and I'm really not a pro user with such an OS.

I've already read the user manual and I've checked here to find out if someone has my same problem, so I hope I'm not repeating any questions.

I'm just trying to produce the very first PDF from a template I'm writing down, and I obtain this:

```
-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I get is a problem of configuration, but I don't know what should I insert in the configuration panel.

This is my file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Bruno Pescara}
\title{Investigation of ionization relaxation dynamics via femtosecond laser-spectoscopy}
\begin{document}
\index{•}
\chapter{introduction}
abilità di guardare nel piccolo sia come dimensione ma anche come velocità, pensavano che la spettroscopia fosse finita ma poi hanno fatto sta cosa ed è andata come è adata
\chapter{Theory}
\section{mass spectroscopy}
\section{electron ionization}
\section{particle size analysis}
\chapter{Methods}
\section{mass spectroscopy}
\section{electron ionization}
\section{particle size analysis}
\chapter{Results}
\section{mass spectroscopy}
\section{electron ionization}
\section{particle size analysis}
\chapter{Discussion}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

I'm using Texmaker version 4.4.1 and Mac OS X Yosemite (the last one).

Comment: Have you tried running something like `latex your_filename.tex` straight from the terminal?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure, that you have a complete and correct TeX system installed which includes above all the distribution, an editor and maybe a PDF viewer. The recommended distribution for OS X is [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/). Download and install it.

To check whether everything works fine, create a minimal document named `testfile.tex`

```
% testfile.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

and save it on your desktop. Then open the Terminal and navigate to the folder into which you saved the file, in this case `~/Desktop/`, with

```
cd ~/Desktop/
```

and then run `pdflatex` with

```
pdflatex testfile.tex
```

That should generate a PDF containing “Hello World!” (and a page number). If this worked your TeX distribution was installed correctly.

---

Now you maybe have to change the setting of you editor. For `pdflatex` the setting should be

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

where `pdflatex` is the TeX program, `-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode` are options and `%.tex` the placeholder for the actual file. With this setting you should now be able to compile the file in you editor. If this *doesn’t* work try this setting:

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```